# Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia driver dell 5593 10th gen processor not working

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, cpu

I installed ubuntu 18.04 next to windows 10 on dell 5593 with 10th gen intel processor and nvidia mx230. 
I couldn't boot into ubuntu because i didn't have the nvidia driver installed and the basic driver had problems with hdaudio codec. I managed to boot into rescue mode and installed nvidia-435 successfully.
The newest driver i found in repository was nvidia-435 and ubuntu now boots, however i can see in nvidia-smi or even System details that it doesn't work (shows Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)). 
One of the problems i encountered atm is not working brightness adjustement. 
Is it connected with the fact that i have intel 10th gen processor and its not fully supported by ubuntu 18?
I found topics suggesting to change grub file, but none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be manually upgrading kernel to latest 5.3.9 version (i used ukuu).